# Imprimir las dos últimas cifras del año de nacimiento pero alfabéticamente

Tags: c

Debo ingresar el año de nacimiento e imprimir las dos últimos cifras del año de nacimiento, pero en caracteres.

La tabla de equivalencias sería esta (los números son cambiados por las letras).

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
A B C D E F G H I J
```

Por ejemplo, si ingreso `1997`, me tiene que imprimir  `JH`.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo en *C*?

Comment: Bienvenido a SO, te sugiero que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona esta comunidad y cómo se deben hacer las preguntas, con un [ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Quisiera saber para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Primero se le pide al usuario el año, luego se muestran dos caracteres, mediante `%c` en `printf`, el primero es el lugar de las decenas del año, el segundo, el de las unidades.

1. Decenas: Al resto de dividir el año por 100, se lo divide por 10.
2. Unidades: El resto de dividir el año por 10.

En ambos casos, se le suma el valor del caracter `'A'`, para que empiece desde la primera letra del abecedario.

Nota: La variable la llamo `anio` en vez de `año` porque en *C* no está permitido el caracter `ñ`.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int anio;
    printf("Ingresar el anio: ");
    scanf("%d",&anio);
    printf("%c%c\n",(anio%100)/10+'A',anio%10+'A');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se que quieres hacer como tal. Pero si hablas de un año deberia tener 4 cifras.
Por tanto deberias verificar eso.
Un numero es una suma de cifras entre 0 y 9 multiplicadas por potencias de 10.

Ejemlpo.

- 1997 = 1 * 1000 + 9 * 100 + 9 * 10 + 7

Sabiendo esto, puedes sacar los digitos de tu numero de hay proceder a tomar los dos ultimos y 
comparar con vector donde tengas las letras y lo que haces es que el numero que tienes buscas la letra en 
esa posicion y listo

Ejemplo:

Guardaste digito:

```
 int n1 = 1, n2 =9, n3=9, N4=7;
// (0=a,1=b,2=c,3=d,4=e,....9=j)
Vector[] = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j};
// para  n1 = 1

Vector[n1] = Vector[1] = a  // Esto es lo que deberia arrojar
Vector[n2] = Vector[9] = j  // Esto es lo que deberia arrojar
Vector[n3] = Vector[9] = j  // Esto es lo que deberia arrojar
Vector[n4] = Vector[7] = h  // Esto es lo que deberia arrojar
```

si tienes un numero de tres cifras, abc, a = abc / 100, b = (abc % 100) / 10 y c = abc % 10 (recuerda que en C, si tanto el dividendo como el divisor son números enteros, la división da como resultado el cociente del algoritmo de la división entre enteros)

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
        int numero, a, b, c, d;
        printf("Escribe un numero entero con 4 digitos: ");
        scanf("%d", &numero);

        if (numero >= 1000){
            if (numero <= 9999){
                a = numero / 1000;
                b = (numero % 1000) / 100;
                c = (numero % 1000) % 100 / 10;
                d = ((numero % 1000) % 100) % 10;

                printf("%d   %d   %d   %d\n", a, b, c, d);
                }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

En este post hay otro ejemplo de hacer si quiere ver

> Fuente: [Separar numeros en digitos individuales](https://foro.elhacker.net/programacion_cc/separar_numeros_en_digitos_individuales-t406137.0.html)

Comment: Claro, son 4 cifras. pero la idea es sacar las ultimas 2 cifras e imprimir en caracteres. Por eso si yo ingreso 1997, tendria que imprimir el 97, pero en caracteres. 9=J, 7=H = JH.

Comment: Arriba te explico como sacarlo. 
Si sacas las 4 cifras, pero solo vas a usar n3 y n4  y procedes a imprimirlo.

Answer (score -2):

Yo meteria las letras en un diccionario, poniendo de llave la letra y de valor el número.

Después usaría:

```
int.TryParse(valor.Substring(x, 1), out y) == true)
```

Esta línea recorrerá el año. Sacaría los 2 últimos dígitos y los buscaría en el diccionario.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que `int.TryParse()` funciona en C? uhmm.

Answer (score -2):

Yo lo hice así no se si es lo que buscas

```
string año = "", ultimodigito = "", penuntimidigito = "", letra1 = "", letra2 = "";
Dictionary<int, string> letras = new Dictionary<int, string>();
letras.Add(1, "A");
letras.Add(2, "B");
letras.Add(3, "C");
letras.Add(4, "D");
letras.Add(5, "E");
letras.Add(6, "F");
letras.Add(7, "G");
letras.Add(8, "H");
letras.Add(9, "I");
letras.Add(0, "J");
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese año");
año = Console.ReadLine();
penuntimidigito= año.Substring(3, 1);
ultimodigito = año.Substring(2, 1);
foreach (var item in letras)
{
    if (item.Key == int.Parse(penuntimidigito))
    {
        letra1 = item.Value;                
    }
    if (item.Key == int.Parse(ultimodigito))
    {
            letra2 = item.Value;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(letra1+""+letra2);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: -1. La pregunta pide hacerlo en el lenguaje C, no en C#. Además, deberías al menos formatear tu código.

Comment: Ademas, no agregues una respuesta nueva, mejor edita la respuesta ya agregada.

Comment: Eso si es mi primeras en ente foro ayer abrí la cuenta, perdon

Comment: Dale cuando salga del trabajo lo hago en C pero la lógica es la misma